¿Es el adjetivo "filiatorio" correcto en el español?
Como por ejemplo al hablar de "datos filiatorios".
Me suena raro y no encontre la palabra "filiatorio" en el diccionario de la RAE.

Sí, es correcto.
No aparece directamente en el DRAE, pero sí se explica cómo se deriva el término en la definición del sufijo -torio


suf. Forma adjetivos y sustantivos deverbales. Toma la forma -atorio si el verbo base es de la primera conjugación; -itorio, si es de la tercera. Los adjetivos denotan relación con la acción del verbo
base. Dedicatorio, definitorio.


Es decir, datos filiatorios son aquellos que se usan para llevar a cabo la acción de filiar


tr. Tomar los datos personales de alguien.

Sin.:  registrar, fichar, inscribir, anotar, apuntar.

Podemos concluir que datos filiatorios es perfectamente válido y que es solo una forma rebuscada, quizás propia del lenguaje jurídico, de decir datos personales, aquellos que sirven para identificar a una persona.
